# How do I find a difference between two moment.unix()

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I convert a unix timestamp based on a time zone like this:

```
var event_time = moment.unix(first_start).tz(timezone);
```

Then I need to find out:

1. if event_time is the same day as today (`moment()`)
2. if the difference between today and event_time is less or equals 30 minutes
3. otherwise return formatted `event_time.format('HH:mm'`)

But turns out that I get alway false doing this

```
moment.unix(event_time).tz(timezone).isSame(moment())
```

Comment: What's first_start? Can you put more code?

Comment: I was supposed to be event_time (updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify time resolution for isSame. If time resolution is not given, the return value indicates that dates are equal. I think you're looking for something like this?

```
if ( event_time.isSame(moment(), 'day') ) {
    // Stuff?
} else if( Math.abs(event_time.diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'minutes')) <= 30 ||
           Math.abs(event_time.diff(moment().endOf('day'), 'minutes')) <= 30) {
    // ... More stuff?
} else {
    return event_time.format('HH:mm')
}
```

Source: http://momentjs.com/docs/